# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in ASP(vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I came across to this code that creates control dynamically. I tried it. However, whenever I run it,  Object reference not set to an instance of an object error pops out and points out to a certain line in the code( i put ---> on the line). I'm a newbie in this programming language. I don't know what to do.

Here's the code I got:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
'Imports System.Data.Odbc

Partial Public Class main
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Private controlCounter As Integer = 0
Private myControlList As List(Of String)

Protected Overrides Sub LoadViewState(ByVal savedState As Object)
    MyBase.LoadViewState(savedState)
    myControlList = DirectCast(ViewState("myControlList"), List(Of String))
    For Each ctlID As String In myControlList
        controlCounter += 1
        Dim hyper As New HyperLink()
        hyper.ID = ctlID
        Dim lineBreak As New LiteralControl("<br />")
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(hyper)
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lineBreak)
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        myControlList = New List(Of String)()
        ViewState("myControlList") = myControlList
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    controlCounter += 1
    Dim hyper As New HyperLink()
    hyper.Text = "a new text Box"
    hyper.ID = "hyperlink" + controlCounter.ToString()
    Dim lineBreak As New LiteralControl("<br />")
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(hyper)
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lineBreak)
  -->      myControlList.Add(hyper.ID)
    ViewState("myControlList") = myControlList

End Sub
End Class
```

please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A button click initiates a postback, and you only set `myControlList` to a thing if the request is *not* a post back, so it's nothing.

If you're wanting to create the list on page load, and then only keep adding to it with subsequent clicks, say, then you'll need to shove `myControlList` into the Session, or something, after creating it, then on button click retrieve it again, add to it, and re-set it in the Session.

To do this add and getting from the Session stuff, do,

```
Session("someDistinctKey") = myControlList;
myControlList = CType(Session("someDisctintKey"), List(Of String))
```

respectively.

Comment: Sir, how to shove myControlList into the Session?